# DiscordBot JDA get all Messages in a Channel

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Hey I tried to get all the messages from a channel but I always failed. I've already searched for similar questions and tried them but I couldn't find a solution...

I also tried @Minn's solution but it didn't work:

```
channel.getHistory().retrievePast(2)
       .map(messages -> messages.get(1)) // this assumes that the channel has at least 2 messages
       .queue(message -> { // success callback
           System.out.println("The second most recent message is: " + message.getContentDisplay();
       });
```

Or rather, I didn't manage to rescript it so that all messages are collected.

Answer (score 3):

I found a Solution...

```
MessageHistory history = MessageHistory.getHistoryFromBeginning(channel).complete();
List<Message> mess = history.getRetrievedHistory();
```

Comment: Please rephrase the ask as a question,  How to get DiscordBot JDA to retrieve all of the Messages in a a Channel?

Comment: The answer is ok, but the question needs work.